# which model to select based on anova II table with Chisq test

Tags: r, anova, chi-squared-test, deviance, lme4-nlme

I have three regression binomial models in R (GLMM) for which I have the following anova table.

[image: anovaII]

Now, which is the model of the best fit based on the metrics in the table? Is it model 2 since it has the lowest BIC value?

I read somewhere that the best fitting model should have a lower residual deviance, AIC and BIC values than other models. The p-value threshold here is p<0.5.

In addition, how can I calculate the Chisq,Chi Df and p-value of model2 in R since these are not provided in the first row?

Comment: The Chisq values are for differences with the previous row. There is no previous row for model2 so no Chisq.

Comment: Ok but still would model2 be the model of the best fit?